# v4l2 -> QByteArray(?) -> QWebsocket -> internet -> {PC, Android, web}

Tags: qt, video-streaming, webcam, motion, v4l2

as you can assume from the tile, I would like to broadcast a webcam stream to different clients. I know that there are many solutions (as motion), but I have already a working infrastructure based on a Qt server software and a websocket as connection to the outer world.

I have read source code of other linux applications like kopete and motion to find out the most efficient way, but don't come to a good conclusion. Another goal is to keep the websocket stream in a format which can be decoded by e.g. javascript in a browser.
The source, a v4l2 device, is already accessed. There a different formats (YUV, MJPEG, ...) but I don't know which (standard) format to choose when it comes to streaming. Another requirement is to save the stream to a harddrive and to process those stream (opencv?) to find motion. So the question is should i transmit a QByteArray thats zlib compressed or use mjpeg, which I don't know how to use. The used webcam is a uvcvideo device:

```
enter ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : MJPEG

    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)code
```

To be honest, I am not sure how motion does this in detail, because this might be the ways to choose.

Thanks 
small

Comment: Forget to mention: The client is always requiesting a single image,

Comment: please do not use "comments" to add additional info to your question - update the question instead.